# Check response form ajax call and compare

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble with this code below.

When submitting a form I want to display a modal view.
The modal view is working fine, but it shows the same modal view everytime I submit.

The #status1 returns modal view with success markup and #status returns alert markup.

I'm getting OK in reponse if success og nothing otherwise.
I've checked the response and it is OK with capitalized letters.

So i can't figure out why it's skiping the check for the #status1 modal view.

So is there anyone who can tell me why?

```
$('#form').submit(function(/*DOMEvent*/ e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('action'),
        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.post(url, data, function(response){

            if($(".costatus").text() == 'OK'){
                $("#status1").modal("show"); 
            } else {
                $("#status").modal("show"); 
            }

            console.log(response);
            });
        });
```

Best regards
Palle

Comment: You aren't checking response in the if-statement

Comment: `$(".costatus").text()` gives you the text content of the first element in the page with class `costatus`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.
Can you help me to the right check.
I've changed it to this, but get the same result.

   if(response == 'OK'){
   $("#status1").modal("show"); 
   } else {
   $("#status").modal("show"); 
   }

Answer (score 0):

If you able to use bool values then use bool values for status checks. Let´ assume the response is json:

```
{status:true, code:200}
```

The use the following logic to check

```
if(response.status){
... some logic
}
```